# Capture Linux grep command to variable in C

Tags: c, linux

The following Linux command returns a single integer representing the number of cores on the processor (physical, not virtual cores):

```
grep ^cpu\\scores /proc/cpuinfo | uniq |  awk '{print $4}'
```

What is the best way to call this command in C and assign the result to a variable?

Comment: [popen](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html).

Comment: Is your question "how to run an arbitrary shell command and get it's output" or "how to get the number of CPU cores" ?

Comment: @kaylum - the second answer (with 57 votes) looks promising -- fp = popen(cmd, "r").  I will try it in C now.

Comment: @Eugene Sh. - the command returns the number of physical cores, so my question is your first question, how to run the arbitrary command and assign its output to a variable in C.

Comment: @kaylum - no, that's a file command.  I will try with system.

Comment: If you want to find the number of physical cores, you don't need to use external processes...

Comment: @Shawn - how do we do that in C?

Comment: `fopen()` and reading /proc/cpuinfo yourself is one way. (There's also `get_nprocs()` or the equivalent `sysconf()` call, but I'm pretty sure that includes virtual cores)

Comment: @Shawn - the command I gave above returns the physical processor count.  My question is now to issue that command in C and capture its result to a variable.

Comment: It's an xy problem. You want x. You think y is a good approach when it's not, and are focusing on that instead of your real question.  Or to put it another way, you're trying to use a semi to deliver an envelope. Just read the file in C using the normal stdio routines and extract the number. No need to get a shell or external programs involved.

Comment: Reading all of /proc/cpuinfo then parsing it seems like the semi approach -- can you clarify what you mean.  The command I gave delivers the answer as a single integer.  I just need to capture it to a variable in C.  Otherwise, I'm not sure exactly what approach you recommend.

Comment: `popen` is the way to do it if you want to run an external command. Not sure what you mean by "that's a file command". You can't do it (as easily) with `system` as that does not give you access to the output directly.

Comment: I would look at using `fopen` to open the file for reading, and then use `getline` to parse line-by-line `strncmp` against the string you expect at the start of the line) until you find the correct line and then read the numeric value with `strtoul`.